# Jquery UI date picker Customization bug

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

Code reference:https://jsfiddle.net/manikiran1/9cmLuuk1/

I selected start date as jan 1 2013 then the end date should be prepopulated with start date and it will show the drop down automatically by getting focus(if end date is empty ) now drop down will show calendar options in jan,2013 so that i can able to  select any date in this selection.Now my problem is
        1.I selected start date as jan 1,2013
        2.the end  date will automatically show the calendar drop down with the start date selection.
       3. now i want to select the year as 2015 but it is not changing in the    calendar drop down menu for first time selection.But if u select again it is working fine.
        So please help me to avoid this bug.

```
  $("#datepicker1").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
       var a = $("#datepicker1").datepicker("getDate");
       var b = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
       var c = new Date(a);
       var d = new Date(b);
       if (a == null) {
         document.getElementById("datepicker1").focus();
         $("#datepicker1").datepicker('setDate', selectedDate);
       }
       if (d.getTime() == c.getTime()) {
         document.getElementById("datepicker1").focus();
         $("#datepicker1").datepicker('setDate', selectedDate);
       }
     }
   });
   $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
     maxDate: new Date(),
     yearRange: "2011:new Date()",
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     dateFormat: "M dd,yy",
     onClose: function(selectedDate) {
       var b = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
       if (b == null) {
         document.getElementById("datepicker").focus();
       }
     }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this

```
onChangeMonthYear:function(y, m, i){                                
 var d = i.selectedDay;
 $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(y, m - 1, d));
 },
```

the complete function will be

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
 maxDate: new Date(),
 yearRange: "2011:new Date()",
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 dateFormat: "M dd,yy",
 onChangeMonthYear:function(y, m, i){                                
 var d = i.selectedDay;
 $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(y, m - 1, d));
 },
 onClose: function(selectedDate) {
   var b = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
   if (b == null) {
     document.getElementById("datepicker").focus();
   }
 }
 });
```

the fiddler : https://jsfiddle.net/6h3zto4y/